# Adding a bitmap image from list to a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` where I want to drop images and display them right after.
When I do it with a path it works, but when I try to add a bitmap instead, it shows me `System.Drawing.Bitmap`[image]

To add it there, I get the path and then transform it to byte(I do that because I need to save it in DB).

I do something like this:

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile(img);
byte[] Test = ConvertImageToBinary(image1);
ImagesList.Add(new ImagesList()
{
    ImagePath = img,
    Data = ConvertImageToBinary(image1),
    ConvertedData = ConvertBinaryToImage(Test)
});

listbox.ItemsSource = ImageArray;
```

WPF:

```xml
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Image  Height="100"  Width="100" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ConvertedData}"  />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I tried to set it as `<Image>` and as `<ContentControl>` but neither worked.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is a WinForms type, not WPF. Use `BitmapImage` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap
```

Is a GDI+ implementation of a bitmap. WPF cannot directly use GDI+ rendering. The bitmap option for it is [BitmapSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource?view=netframework-4.8). You can use [BitmapSource.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.create?view=netframework-4.8) to build one from the bitmap data.